# how to create a borderless child window in silverlight 3?

Tags: silverlight

I WPF there is the WindowsStyle property. I need to know whether exists something similar in silverligth or any method to create a child window without a visible frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can get is to take charge of the entire template for the child window.

The template being used is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070(VS.95).aspx).

Rip the template and place it in a Style resource (probably best if you dump it in its own ResourceDictionary XAML file and use MergedDictionaires in App.Xaml to make it available)

Now play around with the template removing the border (its actually a set of borders).

Comment: Anthony

Thanks a lot, this was really helpful!

Regards

Alfonso

Comment: it may be a late comment, but it was helpfull